# Bootstrap Modal Video keeps playing when closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video, modal-dialog

I have written an video indexing program using MySQL and PHP and send the video to a modal window. However, the video keeps playing when modal window is closed. Here is the code. I am a novice at this and apologize in advance. I have searched the internet for an answer without any solution.

```
 <a href"#" class="video" data-video="<?php echo $vidpath . $file_mp4_v3;?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"><?php echo $movie_name_v3 ;?></a>


  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body justify-content-center">
                    <div class="video" id="divVideo">
                        <video autoplay id="myVideo" width="1280" height="720" controls="false" poster="" class="myvideo img-fluid">
                                <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="" type="video/ogv" />
                            <source src="" type="video/wmv" />
                <script>
                     
                </script>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' video').load();
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });

})


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you set the `src` attribute to start playing the video you can empty it to stop the video.

You can use [the modal bootstrap events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events) `hide.bs.modal` or `hidden.bs.modal` to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is appreciated. I have tried several variations of the hide.bs.modal or hidden.bs.modal functions in the above without success. Where would I place this command and how would it be scripted correctly. Thank you for your help, it is appreciated.